# Wordpress SQL data query layout

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using SQL Executioner in Wordpress Admin and trying to get a list of data from a table (wp_postmeta) using the following:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value from wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = "_wprm_reservation_name" 
UNION 
(SELECT post_id, meta_value from wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = "_wprm_reservation_phone_number");
```

This returns the information that I require but the layout is wrong. I am getting two columns: one with the post_id number and meta_value (persons name) listed then after all those I am getting the post_id number repeated and the telephone number.

Ideally I am trying to get the phone number to be placed next to the persons name. The post_id is the key as the number is used for both the name and phone number.

I have tried number variations trying to understand the UNION statement but cannot get this to work. Can anyone advise please where I am going wrong here?

Comment: The query returns the data and has no direct relation to the layout. Your problem lies elsewhere. The SQL union only combines data from the 2 queries into a single result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union working like this, see the documentation. What you need is a subquery, or a join. This is with subquery:

```
SELECT wppm.post_id, wppm.meta_value, 

(SELECT wppmphone.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta wppmphone 
 WHERE wppmphone.meta_key = "_wprm_reservation_phone_number" 
 AND wppmphone.post_id = wppm.post_id) AS phoneNum

 FROM wp_postmeta wppm WHERE meta_key = "_wprm_reservation_name";
```

This is one query, I just separated the subquery by new lines to be readable. This is not tested, but it should like something like this.

Note, I am using aliases for the table names.

Comment: Amazing, many thanks for the input, I can see now where I was completely on the wrong track and now have the list working with your example.